# how to get back to the main story in gta v and how to get back to Franklin's?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, grand-theft-auto-v

So, I'm playing video games much more often now than I used to and made some GTA progress. I'm past the car chase part where you rescue the boat. I've done a couple of side missions with Michael the fitness girl and the race with Franklin and the other guys. I can't figure out how to get back to the main story. I skipped the racing mission eventually because I couldn't ever complete it. But I have my game saved. I can't get back up to the main story no matter what I do. I'm saved in Michael's house.

Also, I used to have Franklin's house saved on the map but I don't anymore. Why is that and how do I get instructions back to Franklin's house? By way of setting the waypoint on my map, I can only go back to Michael's. I mean specifically by waypoint on the map. Otherwise I can go wherever and probably even to Franklin's if I knew where that was. Should I just go to where it shows the house? I haven't edited any settings.

Answer (score 1):

Main Missions are denoted by either *M* or *F* on your map (and another letter later in the game, I don't want to spoil you). By doing these missions you will inevitably advance in the story. Sometimes they take some time to pop up due to daytime or just because you haven't fulfilled a prerequisite such as having a phone conversation. But these prerequisites will be quite apparent so don't worry about them. What I would suggest is to switch characters once in a while and explore a bit. The mission should start eventually.

I could provide more help if you could tell me what story mission you did last. Please refer to the [GTA Wikia](http://gta.wikia.com/Missions_in_GTA_V) for a list of main missions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the last mission you undertook was **Father/Son**.

The next one is **Marriage Counselling**. To start this mission, go to Michael's house with Michael.